# Why does this particular code for a leap year program not work?

Tags: c++

I'm new into coding and I'm trying to make a program to decide whether a 4-digit year is a leap year or not. I know I can find other working code for it here, but I specifically want to know why this particular code I tried didn't work. Could somebody please explain?

I tried to input common years (e.g. 9999), but it gave out 'It is a leap year' instead.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int year;

  std::cout << "Enter a year: ";
  std::cin >> year;

  int len;

  for (len = 0; year > 0; year = year / 10){
    len++;
  }

  if (len != 4){
        std::cout << "It's not a 4 digit number.";
  }

  else {

        if (year % 400 != 0){
            std::cout << "It is a common year.";
        }

        if (year % 4 == 0){
            std::cout << "It is a leap year.";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Pop quiz: if a number is between 1000 and 9999, how many digits are in the number?

Comment: i use codeblocks. but i don't understand why it's giving out 'it is a leap year' instead of 'it is a common year'

Comment: Try printing `year` before you do the checks for whether it's divisible by 400 and 4.

Comment: thanks! i've just found out that even if i put the equation as the loop condition it still remains valid for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter 2020 as input, after

```
for (len = 0; year > 0; year = year / 10)
{
    len++;
}
```

`year` will be 0.

**Then**, you'll check `year % 4`, which will also be 0. You simply need to create another variable to copy the year in, and use this other variable to check the division by 10.

Or, you could check `(year < 10000)` and `(year > 999)` without modifying `year`.

Comment: thanks, this works! so even if i put the statement inside the loop condition, the value still remains the same for the rest of the code, then?

Comment: Yes, you want to look up the "scope" of variable in your book/website. A variable will carry its new value during its whole scope.

Comment: okay, i'll do that. thanks!